# How to populate an array with integers from a FILE?

Tags: c, arrays, io

I am completly lost and have no clue how to get the integers from a file to be inputted into an array. if a file looks like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and I want an array `a[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` then how do I even go about doing this?

would something along the lines of this work?

```
int a[9];
int i;

infile = fopen("test.txt","r");
while(fscanf( infile, "%d", *(a+i) != EOF)
{
     fscanf( infile, "%d", *(a+i))
     i++
}
```

In actuality, I'd like the array to be some arbitrarily large number knowing that the file wont consist of more than that amount, i.e. 1000.

Comment: Hvae you tried it and if so what is the problem?

Comment: @Bourezg - Perhaps (seeing that last couple of questions) it might be wise to get to grips with the debugger

Comment: Would be nice to accept some of the answers given to the previous questions.

Comment: Apologies Ed Heal I know I've kind of abuse the website today.

Comment: No you have not . Just need to learn the ropes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
for (int i = 0; fscanf(infile, "%d", &a[i]) == 1; ++i);
```

Comment: Yeah, `== 1` is better.  No need for an additional status variable.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you include this line twice?

```
fscanf(infile, "%d", *(a+i));
```

Once as a condition and once in the body of the loop?  It's superfluous.  This will work:

```
int i = 0;
while(fscanf(infile, "%d", *(a + i) != EOF)
{
     i++;
}
```

Or better yet, to make it more robust:

```
int i = 0, ret;
while((ret = fscanf(infile, "%d", *(a + i++)) != EOF) && (ret == 1))
    continue;
```

Comment: Could use a `for` loop